# How to change a socket's IP_MULTICAST_IF

Tags: sockets, interface, ip, multicast

I have a Computer with 5 interfaces: 3 with public IPs and 2 local IPs. I am trying to send "HELLO" to a UDP server, but I would like to change the interface to one of the local IP addresses. I did some research and this is the line I need to add in python:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton("64.195.10.11"))
```

with 64.195.10.11 being the IP I want to change to

So my python code looks like this:

```
import socket

MCAST_GRP = '224.0.0.1'
MCAST_PORT = 10222

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton("64.195.10.10"))
sock.sendto("HELLO", (MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))
```

It works perfectly when I change between my 3 public IP addresses. However, it does not work (packet is not delivered) if I put a local IP in the argument. I am not sure if the script does not send, or the server does not receive. What is happening?

SL

Edit: I am listening using two ways:

```
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("", 10222))
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,
                                 socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
                                 socket.inet_aton("224.0.0.1") +
                                 socket.inet_aton("64.195.10.11"))
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 0)

while True:
    print >>sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message'
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)

    print >>sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address)
    print >>sys.stderr, data

    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending acknowledgement to', address
    sock.sendto('ack', address)
```

and using twisted:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.application.internet import MulticastServer

class MulticastServerUDP(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__ (self, group, name):
        self.group = group
        self.name = name
    def startProtocol(self):
        print '%s Started Listening' % self.group
        self.transport.joinGroup(self.group)

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, address):
        print "%s Received:"%self.name + repr(datagram) + repr(address)

reactor.listenMulticast(10222, MulticastServerUDP('224.0.0.1', 'SERVER1'), listenMultiple = True)             
reactor.run()
```

Comment: "it does not work" is not a very helpful problem description. Does the `setsockopt` succeed or fail? Does the `sendto` succeed or fail?

Comment: @SquallLeohart : the server and the local address(private address) you want to test are on the same machine?

Comment: I'm not having a problem with this code at all when I use an [RFC 1918](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) address; wireshark shows the multicast packet going out with no problems

Comment: @TOC: yes, they are on the same machine.

Comment: @David Schwartz: No errors in the code. both of then succeed. The server just does not receive the packet.

Comment: @Mike Pennington: So probably the server just does not receive packets from RFC 1918. Do you have an idea why it's doing that?

Comment: please capture the packet with `tshark -Vi <interface_name> udp and port 10222`.  I can only guess, but if it's leaving the mcast server (and it is), then we need some way to diagnose what's wrong.  How is your machine "listening" for this packet?

Comment: I edited my question to include the listening code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the unicast RFC 1918 IPv4 source address of the listener machine?

Comment: thats the IP of the interface I want to set as default. It's the private IP that I have problems with.

If I change to 64.195.10.11 in both sender and receiver, then the packet is received.

Comment: So let's be clear, you want to send the multicast from a unicast address of 64.194.10.11 to an RFC 1918 address?  If not, please explictly point out the unicast addresses of the sender and receiver, because it's quite possible your problem is more basic than anything to do with Python

Comment: I want to send a multicast from an interface with private IP address (the RFC 1918 in this case), but in order to do that I need to change the default interface, which has IP 64.194.10.11.
The receiver joins the group 224.0.0.1 to listen.

Comment: Please change your sender and listener's multicast address to "239.0.0.1" and let me know whether this helps; please tell me that the sender and listener are connected to the same ethernet switch and in the same Vlan

Comment: I replaced 224.0.0.1 with 239.0.0.1, and it still does not receive.

Comment: Are the sender and listener connected to the same ethernet switch and in the same vlan?  If not, tell us how you have this routed

Comment: Actually, I think it's a firewall issue. Let me confirm this.

Comment: If there is a firewall between your sender and receiver, then you very likely are having problems with the firewall... they tend to cause problems for multicast configurations

Comment: Yes, indeed it is a firewall problem. I sincerely thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: my firewall did not accept udp packet from that RFC1918 IP address.

Answer (score 2):

In case the server and the client are on the same machine (for testing), maybe you need to set `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP` option like this (c Code):

```
int loop_on = 1;
setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, &loop_on, sizeof(loop_on));
```

In python you can try something like this:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 1)
```

Hope this help.

Edit : Adding some trace (From my Linux box)

The code i use is the same as posted by SquallLeohart:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import socket

MCAST_GRP = '224.0.0.1'
MCAST_PORT = 10222

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton("192.168.1.7"))
sock.sendto("HELLO", (MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))
```

And:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("", 10222))
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,
                                 socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
                                 socket.inet_aton("224.0.0.1") +
                                 socket.inet_aton("192.168.1.7"))
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 0)

while True:
    print >>sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message'
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)

    print >>sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address)
    print >>sys.stderr, data

    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending acknowledgement to', address
    sock.sendto('ack', address)
```

I got this output :

```
waiting to receive message
received 5 bytes from ('192.168.1.7', 43761)
HELLO
sending acknowledgement to ('192.168.1.7', 43761)

waiting to receive message
received 5 bytes from ('192.168.1.7', 52326)
HELLO
sending acknowledgement to ('192.168.1.7', 52326)

waiting to receive message
```

And with tcpdump:

```
21:01:33.814728 IP localhost.localdomain.34956 > all-systems.mcast.net.10222: UDP, length 5
21:01:35.364605 IP localhost.localdomain.39078 > all-systems.mcast.net.10222: UDP, length 5
21:01:36.228477 IP localhost.localdomain.49926 > all-systems.mcast.net.10222: UDP, length 5
```

Regards.

Comment: It does not help unfortunately.

It seems like interfaces with similar IP addresses have no problem when I switch them, such as 64.195.10.110, 64.195.10.11, 64.195.10.12

But 192.168.1.75, for example, is an address that I cannot switch to.

Comment: @SquallLeohart: can you use tcpdump and dump some packets here please?

Comment: @SquallLeohart : Yes i post it, i use it on my local LAN on (192.168.1.7)

Comment: Your line about the loop does not help, as it gives me the same problem whether I run the codes on the same machine or two different machine. I just found out that the problem was due to my firewall setting. My code works now. Anyway, thank you very much!